# Processing binary data containing different length

Tags: c, buffer, binaryfiles

So I have some binary data that I read, process and need to "split" into different variables, like this:

```
int *buffer;
buffer = malloc(size); 
fread(buffer,size,1,file);
buffer = foo(buffer);
```

The result looks something like this in my debugger:

```
01326A18 5F4E8E19 5F0A0000
```

I want the first byte ( `01` ) to be int `a`.
The following 4 bytes are the first timestamp `b` (should be `5F186A32`)
The following 4 bytes are the second timestamp `c` (should be `5F198E4E`)
The `0A` is supposed to be int `d`.

My Problem is that I can put the 1 into a, with `(*buffer) & 0xff;`,
 but I'm not able to read the first timestamp correctly since its from second to 5th byte and not align with the int declaration of the buffer.
If I print *(buffer +1) it gives me the second int and prints "`198E4E5F`"
It would be better if I were able to target n byte from every position in my data.

thx in advance.

Comment: I hope that `buffer = foo(buffer);` is just an example because it destroys the memory allocated with`malloc`.

Comment: This post really needs to show your effort, in`C`.  i.e. provide a [mcve], then with that context your problem description may make sense.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `buffer = foo(buffer);` need not destroy the memory. For example, the assignment may be for reflecting `realloc()` done within `foo()`.

Comment: why not to use struct with right variables inside and start reading whole struct at once? Like fread(some_struct, sizeof(struct), 1, file).

Comment: _The following 4 bytes are the first timestamp `b` (should be `5F186A32`)_  What does this even mean?  Where is `b` defined?  You go from looking at the first byte `01`, then say the next 4 bytes are to be converted to timestamp `b`?  Where does `5F186A32` come from?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie That line doesn't "destroy memory"

Comment: @user253751, you are absolutely right! Only a hammer, lightning or an explosion can destroy memory. (But yes, as Mik Cat says, there might be some hidden functionality there, although I doubt it given the task of splitting the buffer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will work on most little-endian platforms.  Just fread the same way.

```
struct {
  uint8_t a;
  uint32_t timeStamp1;
  uint32_t timeStamp2;
  uint8_t d;
} buffer __attribute__((packed));
assert(sizeof buffer == 10);  /* check packing */
```

Comment: `__attribute__` is not standard C.  And of course, as you allude, even on implementations that have that extension, this approach relies on the endianness of the implementation's `uint32_t` to match that used in the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your buffer type as `char*` this will make it point to the 1 byte of chunks. Then if try to get `buffer+2`, it will return the second byte of the buffer, unlike int pointer which will return the 8th byte of the buffer. Do not forget to update your `size` in `malloc` call, since you get your memory with 1 byte chunks in this case. Also [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914183/whats-the-correct-way-to-add-1-byte-to-a-pointer-in-c-c) may be helpful.